# Saving Machine Learning Logs on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

How can i save the logs of machine learing model trained in sagemaker like (Creation time, time taken for a job to learn etc.) on mongoDB

Answer (score 0):

SageMaker Logs are stored in CloudWatch Logs.

Just grab the log stream name for your training job, and extract data with the GetLogEvents API: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_GetLogEvents.html

If you only need job metadata, the DescribeTrainingJob API should be enough: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/API_DescribeTrainingJob.html